# google api php client export data dont show correct results

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I am using google api php client for export data in my website and create new analytic view. in my account I have about 20 sites connecting with google analytic and when I want to export my data for specefic account(with client_secrets json file) it is showing other website information. It is very strange. Please help me.

Comment: Authenticating gives you access to all of the analytics accounts the authenticated user has access to.    Sounds like its working as it should or you are extracting data from the wrong profile id.

Comment: I used client_secrets.json which I downloaded when create new Credentials.

Comment: Client secret json identifies your application and has no relation to your google analytics account what so ever.

Comment: good I fix it thanks :)